# Sorting array systematically in perl

Tags: perl

i had some problem,how to make output more systematically

Comment: have a look at [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Comment: Well, we can't see that output, because we don't have your input data source.

Comment: the input is,data1 data2 data3

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you've got a problem here - you're doing your `print` within a worker, and that's within an `async` block.

The WHOLE POINT of threading and `async` means that execution order is undefined, and thus you're simply never going to get your expected and desired result.

You need to collate and post-process your data if you want it sorted.

So define yourself an output queue, queue your results to it, and collated them after you've ended your threads.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings qw( all );
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw( );

my $output_q = Thread::Queue -> new; 

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

sub worker {
   my ($core) = @_;

   @data1 = qw(john amount );
   @data2 = qw(test1 test2 );
   foreach $loop1 (@data1) {
      foreach $loop2 (@data2) {

         #print("$core $loop1 $loop2\n");
         $output_q -> enqueue ( "$core $loop1 $loop2" ); 
      }
   }
}
{
   my $core_data = "data.txt";
   open( my $core_dat, '<', $core_data )
     or die("Can't open \"$core_data\": $!\n");

   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
   for ( 1 .. NUM_WORKERS ) {
      async {
         while ( defined( my $core = $q->dequeue() ) ) {
            worker($core);
         }
      };
   }

   while ( my $file = <$core_dat> ) {
      chomp($file);
      $q->enqueue($file);
   }

   $q->end();

   $_->join() for threads->list();
   $output_q -> end; 
   #dequeue everything from $output_q and then sort it. 
   print join "\n", sort $output_q->dequeue_nb($output_q -> pending); 
}
```

Note - this will pass back one string per result, and then sort on that. That *might* not be exactly what you want (although it'll work based on what you've given so far).

You could for example:

```
$output_q -> enqueue ( [ $core, $loop1, $loop2 ]);
```

And then treat each `$output_q` item as an array reference, and sort based on that. I would suggest that's probably best framed as another question if that's the road you want to go down though.

Comment: Thanks!i get it,but is that possible collated them while/before the threads running?

Comment: You can collate as you go, but you  can't sort an incomplete list. Nor do you know the execution sequence of the threads.